# OWL Class Expression for Data Property

Tags: java, semantic-web, owl, owl-api

In my ontology, I have an individual that has this data property

`hasName "somaName"^^string`,

however, when i'm building a class expression and sending to the reasoner for get the instances, I'm getting an empty set with the following query,

```
OWLClassExpression x = schema.getFactory().getOWLDataHasValue(schema.getDataProperty("hasName"), schema.getFactory().getOWLLiteral("somaName"));
System.out.println(reasoner.getInstances(x, true));
```

**the getDataProperty is just a small method:**

```
public OWLDataProperty getDataProperty(String dataProperty){
        return factory.getOWLDataProperty("#"+dataProperty,pm);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code snippet works, compare it to your code to see what's different. You should use a reasoner that support this type of construct (Hermit does).

```
//Initiate everything
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
String base = "http://www.example.org/";
OWLOntology ontology = manager.createOntology(IRI.create(base + "ontology.owl"));
OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
//Add the stuff to the ontology
OWLDataProperty hasName = factory.getOWLDataProperty(IRI.create(base + "hasName"));
OWLNamedIndividual john = factory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(base + "john"));
OWLLiteral lit = factory.getOWLLiteral("John");
OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom ax = 
                  factory.getOWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom(hasName, john, lit);
AddAxiom addAx = new AddAxiom(ontology, ax);
manager.applyChange(addAx);

//Init of the reasoner
//I use Hermit because it supports the construct of interest
OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new Reasoner.ReasonerFactory();
OWLReasoner reasoner = reasonerFactory.createReasoner(ontology);
reasoner.precomputeInferences();

//Prepare the expression for the query
OWLDataProperty p = factory.getOWLDataProperty(IRI.create(base + "hasName"));
OWLClassExpression ex = 
                factory.getOWLDataHasValue(p, factory.getOWLLiteral("John"));

//Print out the results, John is inside
Set<OWLNamedIndividual> result = reasoner.getInstances(ex, true).getFlattened();        
for (OWLNamedIndividual owlNamedIndividual : result) {
    System.out.println(owlNamedIndividual);
}
```

Comment: +1. But, how to add `OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom ax` to my `OWLClass unknownClass = factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create(baseIRI + "UnknownClass"));` and than save ontology? Can you help me please???